# Keras Convolution Neural Network Dimensions Question

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network

I am interested in going from a 3-D matrix to a 1-D matrix.
1000 rows, 4 columns, 16 sample to 16 sample with 1of4 diseases.

I recall matrix algebra: AX +B = Y
In this case say B=0, Y= 16x1
Then how does the dimension of AX work out in this fashion? What layer can I use for Y to eventually get a dimension of 16x1 with 4 categories?

And would I start the convolution network with a shape like this:

conv2D(filter,kernel, input_shape=(16,1000,4))

How would I end it with a layer that gives me 4 categories ie dense(4)?
Please give an example.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried keras.layers.Flatten() which flattens some-D matrix into 1-D Dense-compatible matrix? Is it fits as a connector between convolutional and dense in your case?

Comment: Good idea. Let me see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is really difficult for me to understand your question. Do you mean that your input is a feature vector of 1000 dimensions, and in total you have 16 of them, and your network output, i.e. target, is one of four possible diseases?

If this is the case, then you misunderstand CNN's input shape, whose batch size is not accounted (you may use different batch sizes, and thus we want to decouple this param from a model).

Depending on your understanding of the 1000-dim feature, you want to apply some feature normalization before you feed it into a model.

```
from keras.layers import *
from keras.models import Model

# 1. define model parameters
# 1.1 dropout rate, you may want to use 0 first
dropout_rate = 0.2 
# 1.2 mlp structure
fc_nodes = [128, 32, 8] 
# activation, e.g. relu or tanh
activation = 'relu' 

# 2. define model
# 2.1 define input
# note: batch_size=16 is NOT included in shape
feat_in = Input(shape=(1000,), name='feat_in')
# 2.2 define body
x = feat_in
for idx, nb_nodes in enumerate( fc_nodes ) :
    x = Dense( nb_nodes, activation=activation, name='fc-{}'.format(idx) )(x)
    if ( dropout_rate > 0 ) :
        x = Dropout( dropout_rate, name='dropout-{}'.format(idx))(x)
# 2.3 define output
pred_out = Dense( 4, activation='softmax', name='pred_out')(x)
# 2.4 define model
model = Model( inputs=feat_in, outputs=pred_out, name='my_model')

# 3. display model architecture
print model.summary()
```

This model will take in a 2D tensor of shape `(batch_size, 1000)` and predict a 2D tensor of shape `(batch_size, 4)`.

BTW, `Conv2D` should be only used if your input is image-like, which is not your case.

Comment: Yes you are correct. Conv1D should be used. A table with 1000 rows and 5 columns, I have 16 tables. I want that to get to 16 tables each with a prediction of either A or B or C or D.

Comment: I get the error below. Reducing the matrix down to the same size as Y (16x1) to feed into Dense is the hard part I guess.                                                                       ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_101 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (16, 1)

Comment: Just want to make sure I understand correctly. What are your sample input/output and their dimensions? It is unclear whether each table is a sample, or each row is a sample.

Comment: input = 1000x5, output 16x1.

Comment: How should we interpret this output16x1?

Comment: 16 patients input 1000x5, 16 patients out with 4 disease class. Yeah again I don't understand how to reduce the dimensions with the layers down to 16x1.

Comment: OK. I think you want to predict the disease type for each patient, which one out of four possible types. In this case, your output should be `16x4`, where 4 is from the four disease probabilities. To obtain the most likely disease type, you need to apply `argmax( proba, axis=-1)` to the raw disease probability vector, but this part should not be considered in a model.